# DateTime Deserialized as the Day Before - UTC Gotcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I inherited an application which stores dates in local time. I've modernized it and grudgingly continued with a business layer that deals with dates in local time.

My posts to the server are in JSON and I've written Javascript which sends it to the server with offset info included e.g.

```
{"name":"aal","dob":"1921-10-06T00:00:00+10:30"}
```

However, ASP.NET is deserializing this as UTC. So, if I choose 6 July 2016 in a Datepicker, the server deserializes it as 5 July 2016.

My question is simple. How can I have a *meeting of the minds* between client and server. If I choose 6 July, I want to persist 6 July (obviously).

Note: this is NOT WebAPI. Good old vanilla MVC 5.

One the client, I am adding the following code to ensure that the JSON payload which gets posted to the server is not UTC:

```
 // Include offset info in the JSON that gets posted to the server.
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
     return moment(this).format();
}
```

Then, I am using the following code to post it (where dob is the date in question):

```
    var getPotentialDuplicatePatients = function (name, dob) {

        return $http({
            data: { name: name, dob: dob },
            url: "/PatientData/CheckForPotentialPatientDuplicates",
            method: 'POST'
        });

    };
```

And the Action method in the Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckForPotentialPatientDuplicates(string name, DateTime dob)
    {
        var duplicates = Enumerable.Empty<PatientPlusEpCountDto>();

        if (//Authorize(WebConstants.EditAction, WebConstants.SurgeonAndDataManagerProtectedResource) &&
            Execute(() => duplicates = _mediator.Send(new GetPotentialPatientDuplicatesQuery
            {
                DateOfBirth = dob,
                PatientName = name
            })))
        {
            return JsonNet(duplicates);
        }

        return JsonError(Errors);            
    }
```

Another interesting aspect to all this is that DateTime properties of complex objects are not suffering that same misfortune. Above, you can see that the parameter is a native type. Where a complex type, which includes DateTime properties, is posted, all works as expected.

The TimeOfDay is different as between them. With the raw native DateTime, it is including a time of day (even though the JSON object is 12:00am). In the complex type, it is 12:00am as expected.

Runnin with this, I will try wrapping the payload in a complex object (which I will create) and see if that resolves it.

**Update - Temp Resolution**

I've had to write the following horrible hack to get this to work as expected:

```
var transformDob = new DateTime(dob.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
var dateOfBirth = transformDob.Date;
```

And I removed the code which modifies the Date prototype. Now, json requests are back to UTC. Need to test whether it still works with other parts of the app.

Comment: It would be awesome (i.e. necessary) for you to show the code at both ends of the process so that we can verify the behaviour and test a solution.

Comment: First check if your DateTime.Kind has set to local time when deserializing, otherwise use `DateTimeOffset` structure as alternative (see MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx). To clarify this, I prefer include your deserialization code into the question.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I am not performing the deserialization. The .NET Framework is. The DateTime in question is a parameter of an Action method in a controller. Cheers.

Comment: @Enigmativity I will edit the question with some code. There won't be much to write as the deserialization is being performed by the MVC framework.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Interestingly, the Kind property is local. I wonder why it is being deserialized as the day before.

Comment: By reading your code, I understand your JSON string includes standard date e.g. `2016-10-12T00:00:00+10:30`, but DateTime input converts it in `2016-10-11T13:30:00Z` as UTC time. Since the `Kind` property set to Local, `ToLocalTime` method was useless, thus you need `ConvertTime` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) or change source date to ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @onefootswill - Can you show the code in the MVC framework that is performing the deserialization?

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset instead perhaps? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx.